# getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea, grails

I am upgrading my grails 2.5.x application to grails 4.0.8
After adding everything and all dependencies i am getting this error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
```

I found various similar post on the same error but none seems to work. This error seems to be very user specific.

My stacktrace looks like this->

```
C:\Java-11.0.8_10-winx64\bin\java.exe -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file229552621 org.grails.cli.GrailsCli run-app --plain-output
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/idnsuv/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.14/f0a005fb21e7bd9b7ebf04cd2ecda0fc8f3be59d/groovy-2.5.14.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
|Running application...
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/idnsuv/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.14/f0a005fb21e7bd9b7ebf04cd2ecda0fc8f3be59d/groovy-2.5.14.jar) to method java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.lambda$getDeclaredAnnotationsByType$0(java.lang.annotation.Annotation,java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARNING: The hasOne property in class [com.ideas.cma.gft.RateSourceGftServerDetails] should have an initial expression of type Map or Class.
WARNING: The hasOne property in class [com.ideas.cma.gft.RateSourceGftServerDetails] should have an initial expression of type Map or Class.
WARNING: The hasOne property in class [com.ideas.cma.gft.RateSourceGftServerDetails] should have an initial expression of type Map or Class.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/idnsuv/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.14/f0a005fb21e7bd9b7ebf04cd2ecda0fc8f3be59d/groovy-2.5.14.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-03-05 09:49:39.795 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in com.ideas.cma.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class com.ideas.cma.excelExport.myTasks.MyTeamTaskExcelExportService] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass]: InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472)
    at com.ideas.cma.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class com.ideas.cma.excelExport.myTasks.MyTeamTaskExcelExportService] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass]: InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Error instantiated artefact class [class com.ideas.cma.excelExport.myTasks.MyTeamTaskExcelExportService] of type [class org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass]: InvocationTargetException
    at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:170)
    at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:812)
    at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:504)
    at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:775)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.performGrailsInitializationSequence(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:112)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:94)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:231)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:78)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:68)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:161)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3191)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1904)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.MethodInfo.get(MethodInfo.java:70)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.ClassInfo.getMethods(ClassInfo.java:71)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1046)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:462)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:205)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:293)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:443)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:205)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3356)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3354)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3331)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:272)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.reflect.ClassPropertyFetcher.getStaticPropertyValue(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:176)
    at org.grails.core.AbstractGrailsClass.getStaticPropertyValue(AbstractGrailsClass.java:239)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsServiceClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsServiceClass.java:34)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Using java 11 with grails 4.0.8 (grails 4 uses gradle build) in IntelliJ idea.
Running in java 8 doesn't make a difference.

Using pathingJar in gradle as such huge dependencies give the file path/ extention too long error in windows 10

build.gradle(minified)--

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.2.4"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "com.domain.projectname"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"
apply plugin:"com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    //for external-config
    maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/repo/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core:4.0.8"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.199"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails"
    testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"

//    User added
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:external-config:2.0.0'

    //Below are the dependencies which are situated in /lib folder as .jar
    compile name: 'activation'
    compile name: 'axis'
    compile name: 'cma-common'
    compile name: 'commons-collections4-4.1'
    compile name: 'commons-discovery-0.2'
    compile name: 'commons-logging-1.0.4'
    compile name: 'concurrent'
    compile name: 'CSVUpload'
    compile name: 'DynamicJasper-3.0.4'
    compile name: 'hibernate-entitymanager'
    compile name: 'hibernate-search'
    compile name: 'hibernate-validator'
    compile name: 'ideas-intf-integration'
    compile name: 'iText-2.1.4'
    compile name: 'jasperreports-3.1.4'
    compile name: 'jaxb1-impl'
    compile name: 'jaxb-impl'
    compile name: 'jaxb-xjc'
    compile name: 'jaxrpc'
    compile name: 'jbossall-ideas-client'
    compile name: 'jboss-aop-jdk50'
    compile name: 'jboss-jaxws'
    compile name: 'jboss-messaging-client'
    compile name: 'jboss-remoting'
    compile name: 'jboss-saaj'
    compile name: 'jboss-serialization'
    compile name: 'jbossws-client'
    compile name: 'jbossws-common'
    compile name: 'jbossws-spi'
    compile name: 'jboss-xml-binding'
    compile name: 'jms'
    compile name: 'jnp-client'
    compile name: 'jsr173_1.0_api'
    compile name: 'lucene-core'
    compile name: 'mail'
    compile name: 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.20'
    compile name: 'policy'
    compile name: 'saaj'
    compile name: 'sfdcws'
    compile name: 'sqljdbc4-1'
    compile name: 'trove'
    compile name: 'ooxml-schemas-1.3'
    compile name: 'poi-3.17'
    compile name: 'poi-ooxml-3.17'
    compile name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17'
    compile name: 'wsdl4j-1.5.1'
    compile name: 'xercesImpl'
    compile name: 'xmlbeans-3.1.0'
    compile name: 'xpp3_min-1.1.4c'
    compile name: 'xstream-1.3.1'


    runtimeOnly group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'jquery', version: '1.11.1'
    runtimeOnly group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'resources', version: '1.2.14'
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'bubbling', version: '1.5.1'
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'calendar', version: '1.2.1'
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'code-coverage', version: '1.1.6'
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'webflow', version: '2.1.0'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:shiro:1.2.1"
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'yui', version: '2.8.2.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat', version: '7.0.70', ext: 'pom'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:calendar:1.2.1"
    implementation group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'ckeditor', version: '4.5.9.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
    provided "opensymphony:quartz-all:1.6.3"
    runtime  "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    runtime  "org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.0.RELEASE"
    runtime  "org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.0.RELEASE"
    runtime  "org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.1.Final"
    runtime  "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4"
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms:5.1.20.RELEASE'

}

bootRun {
    ignoreExitValue true
    jvmArgs(
        '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always', 
        '-noverify', 
        '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
        '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

grails{
    pathingJar = true
}
```

P.S. -> getting similar errors for other dependencies too -> too a "grails dependency-report" and got this. Dont know how to resolve it.(Below is just a path. Thw hole report is too long)

```
+--- myproject-common (n) //A required jar from my another project
+--- commons-collections4-4.1 (n)
+--- commons-discovery-0.2 (n)
+--- commons-logging-1.0.4 (n)
+--- concurrent (n)
+--- CSVUpload (n)
+--- DynamicJasper-3.0.4 (n)
+--- hibernate-entitymanager (n)
+--- hibernate-search (n)
+--- hibernate-validator (n)
+--- myproject-intf-integration (n) //A required jar from my another project
+--- iText-2.1.4 (n)
+--- jasperreports-3.1.4 (n)
+--- jaxb1-impl (n)
+--- jaxb-api (n)
+--- jaxb-impl (n)
+--- jaxb-xjc (n)
+--- jaxrpc (n)
+--- jbossall-ideas-client (n)
+--- jboss-aop-jdk50 (n)
+--- jboss-jaxws (n)
+--- jboss-messaging-client (n)
+--- jboss-remoting (n)
+--- jboss-saaj (n)
+--- jboss-serialization (n)
+--- jbossws-client (n)
+--- jbossws-common (n)
+--- jbossws-spi (n)
+--- jboss-xml-binding (n)
+--- jms (n)
+--- jnp-client (n)
+--- jsr173_1.0_api (n)
+--- lucene-core (n)
+--- mail (n)
+--- mysql-connector-java-5.1.20 (n)
+--- policy (n)
+--- saaj (n)
+--- sfdcws (n)
+--- sqljdbc4-1 (n)
+--- trove (n)
+--- wsdl4j-1.5.1 (n)
+--- xercesImpl (n)
+--- xmlbeans-3.1.0 (n)
+--- xpp3_min-1.1.4c (n)
+--- xstream-1.3.1 (n)
+--- org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13 (n)
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0 (n)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.18.RELEASE (n)
+--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.1.2 (n)
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2 (n)
+--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2 (n)
+--- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:1.7.2 (n)
\--- org.grails.plugins:jms:2.0.0.RC2 (n)
```

I have also tried deleting .m2, .grails, .gradle, grails  clean and basically everything related to resetting the project

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like your application is not able to find `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`. It may be due to multiple reasons, such as:

- The Apache poi JAR is not present in the classpath. So, you would need to add the corresponding dependencies.
- It may also happen when you have different version of multiple poi libraries, which I think are not compatible with each other. In this case, you need to make sure that every poi dependency is pointing to the same version.
- Lastly, you may want to check that the class with same package is present in the respective version of library. The easiest way to check if you are using JetBrains IntelliJ Idea is to navigate to class.

Comment: did not work, already  tries all of them. It comming for almost all the dependencies i am adding and that to randomly

Comment: There might be something wrong with your project configurations. It would be great if you could share a sample application.

Comment: Soory, can't share the application. If want a specific sonfig file, can send it. Thanks!